# Not able to send Data to next check out page

Tags: expresso-store

Take checkout 2 and checkout 3 as example.

When I send data from checkout2 to checkout3, for some reason, the checkout3, not able to retrieve its data. I have inspected element of checkout2 , all the input fields are in a form, which created by the checkout Tag.

Currently, I am using EE 2.6 and Store 1.6.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some template examples of what you are trying to do?